# Excel: How to add a column from other sheet based on a key column?

Tags: excel, join, merge, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I have 2 list. Both have a lot of column. I would like to insert a column from Sheet2 to Sheet1 based on a ceratin key column. Also sheet2 have much more rows than sheet1 so it ll be inserted only partly and still there ll be elements with no matches. For an example:

Sheet1:

```
Names  ID  Car    Color

John   1   Audi   Empty

Andy   4   Toyota Empty

Mike   3   BMW    Empty

Tony   2   Suzuki Empty
```

Sheet2:

```
ID  Cost Color

6   200  Blue

3   200  Red

4   300  Green

5   100  Red

1   50   Black
```

I would like to get the "color" from Sheet2 to Sheet1 by using the "ID". Using Excel 2010. I suspect I need INDEX+MATCH combination, but the examples I can find are not detailed and more simple so I coudn't figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about inserting this formula on Column D in the first row, then dropping the formula down:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!$1:$1048576,3,FALSE)
```

Or to find the column that contains "Color", use Index Match Match, as follows:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1048576,MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!A:A,0),MATCH("Color",Sheet2!$1:$1,0))
```

This will find the value in Column B in Sheet2 and give you the row number, then it will find the Column that contains "Color" and return the Column number, with those two numbers Index will return your color.